# . Определите минимум и максимум среди чисел, которые оканчиваются на 3 и делятся на 7

Tags: python, python-3.8

В файле содержится последовательность целых чисел. Элементы принимают целые значения от 1 до 10000 включительно. Определите минимум и максимум среди чисел, которые оканчиваются на 3 и делятся на 7.

В качестве ответа запишите сначала минимум, а потом максимум без пробелов и разделителей. Например, если минимум равен 99, а максимум - 1234, то ответ 991234.

Самая большая проблема, что в моём файле в конце чисел, стоит \n. И при добавлении в массив этих чисел добавляется и \n тоже. Но даже, когда я удалил \n, решение дальше не идёт.

```
mas = []
f = open("17.txt").read().splitlines()
if f % 10 == 3 and f % 7 == 0:
   mas.append(f)
   print(f)
```

Comment: Подсказка: может следует использовать цикл для прохода по элементам?

Comment: Приводите к int...

Answer (score 0):

```
mas = []
f = open("17.txt").read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(f)):
   if int(f[i]) % 10 == 3 and int(f[i]) % 7 == 0:
       mas.append(f[i])
mas.sort()
print(mas[0],mas[-1])
```

Воспользовался советом пройтись циклом по элементам.